# Navigation bar is not set up properly on one page but is on the other. Is there something I'm missing?

Tags: html, css, caret

**Here's the page it isn't working on code.**

```
<!DOCType html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Home</title>
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6044876b2c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    
    <style>
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 15px;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: White;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: rgb(66, 135, 219);
}
      body {
        font-family: "Montserrat";
        
        background-color:rgb(161, 204, 247);
      }
      img {
        float:center;
        width:250px;
        height:400px;
        margin:10px;
        border-color:White;
        border-style:solid;
        border-radius:10px;
      }
      
    </style>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <nav>
      <input type="checkbox" id="check">
      <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </label>
      <label class="logo">Registred Nursing</label>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Education.html">Education</a></li>
        <li><a href="Info.html">More Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="Usage.html">Comput Sci</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <section>
      
    </section>
    
  <strong><header style="color:White;">A Highly Respected Career</header></strong>
  
  <img src="talking.jpg" alt="Group of Nurses Talking" class="center"
  style="width:704px;height:421px">
  <font size="2"><p style="color:#828282;text-align: left">phoenix.edu - How to become a registered nurse</p></font>
  
 <font size="5"><p> A registered nurse is a nurse who has passed the NCLEX-RN exam and achieved their certification. They're eligible to work in many different departments such as the ER, mental health unit, schools, and so much more. Continue to explore this site to find out more!</p></font>
  
  <a href="Home.html">Current Page |</a>
  <a href="Education.html">Next Page |</a>
  <a href="Info.html">3 |</a>
  <a href="Usage.html">4 </a>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

**Here's the page IT IS working on code.**

```
<!DOCType html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Home</title>
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6044876b2c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    
    <style>
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 15px;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: White;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: rgb(66, 135, 219);
}
      body {
        font-family: "Montserrat";
        
        background-color:rgb(161, 204, 247);
      }
      img {
        float:center;
        width:250px;
        height:400px;
        margin:10px;
        border-color:White;
        border-style:solid;
        border-radius:10px;
      }
      
      </style>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <nav>
      <input type="checkbox" id="check">
      <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
      <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </label>
      <label class="logo">Tasks &amp; Salary</label>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Education.html">Education</a></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="Info.html">More Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="Usage.html">Comput Sci</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <section>
      
    </section>
    
  <strong><header style="color:White;">Read for more info!</header></strong>
  
<h2 style="color:White;text-align:center">The Tasks Of A Registered Nurse</h2>
  
  <img src="blocks.jpg" alt="Wooden Blocks W/ The Word Task" class="center"
  style="width:504px;height:321px">
  <font size="2"><p style="color:#828282;text-align: center">Project Management Tips | Info: <a href="https://www.allnursingschools.com/registered-nursing/job-description/">allnursingschools.com</a></p></font>
  
 <font size="5"><p>The tasks of a registered nurse can consist of monitoring/recording patients' vital signs, monitoring/recording patients' progress, administering medications and treatments, drawing blood, and collecting lab work. They often have the task of going around saying hello to patients, patient admissions and, discharges.</p></font>
 
 <h2 style="color:White;text-align:center">Salary</h2>
 <img src="salary.jpg" alt="Clipart of someone getting handed money." class="center"
 style="width:304px;height:321px">
 <font size="2"><p style="color:#828282;text-align: center">iStock | Info: <a href="https://www.trustedhealth.com/nurse-salary-guide/alabama#:~:text=The%20registered%20nurse%20salary%20in,is%20approximately%20%2437.31%20per%20hour">trustedhealth.com</a></p></font>
 
 <font size="5"><p>The expected national(U.S) salary for a nurse is $77,600. The national wage is $37.31 per hr. However, both may vary depending on the state and/or country one may live in. </p></font>
  
  <a href="Home.html">1 |</a>
  <a href="Education.html">Go Back |</a>
  <a href="Info.html">Current Page |</a>
  <a href="Usage.html">Next Page </a>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

**Here's the CSS**

```
h1 {
  text-align:center;
  font-size:87px;
  background-color:White;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

p {
  color:White;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}

.html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

body {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
}

nav {
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo {
  color: rgb(175, 213, 252);
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 80px;
  padding: 0 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: rgb(161, 204, 247);
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 7px 13px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.active,a:hover {
  background: rgb(66, 135, 219);
  transition: .5s;
}

.checkbtn {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: rgb(161, 204, 247);
  float: right;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

#check {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 952px) {
  label.logo {
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-left: 50px;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 858px) {
  .checkbtn {
    display: block;
  }
  ul {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #2c3e50;
    top: 80px;
    left: -100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .5s;
  }
  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    margin: 50px 0;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  a:hover,a.active {
    background: none;
    color: rgb(66, 135, 219);
  }
  #check:checked ~ ul {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

I looked compared both codes to see if I notice the issue unfortunately I haven't. I'm new to this so please feel free to correct any other unrelated problems too. If you would like me to provide a picture I'll happily do so.

[What it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc8aB.png)

[What it shouldn't look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UTFF.png)

Comment: both navigation looks same and works good. may I know what is the exact issue ?

Comment: @ParTha It's difficult for me to explain but I can put a picture of the problem, I think that would help.

Comment: yes pls add picture

Comment: @ParTha I did, I hope it works!

Comment: check my code. hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Yes I got it

Try this:

```
.logo {
color: rgb(175, 213, 252);
font-size: 35px;
line-height: 80px;
padding-left: 100px;  <-- I just updated this padding
font-weight: bold;
```

}

Hope this help cheers...!